# Laravel How to display related products?

Tags: laravel

[image: Products in Random Order]

I have ShopController . Now I am displaying products in random order from database.
Here is the code

```
$productsLike = Product::with('categories')->where('slug', '!=', $slug)->inRandomOrder()->take(4)->get();
```

What i should do to display products related to the same category as current product?

Answer (score 2):

I would make a [`local scope`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) on your `Product` model to make things reusable.

```
public function scopeRelatedProducts($query, $count = 10, $inRandomOrder = true)
{
    $query = $query->where('category_id', $this->category_id)
                   ->where('slug' '!=' $this->slug);

    if ($inRandomOrder) {
        $query->inRandomOrder();
    }

    return $query->take($count);
}
```

Then you could do something like:

```
$related = Product::relatedProducts(4, true)->with('categories')->get();
```

This assumes the column your `Product` table stores the relationship to a `Category` follows the Laravel naming convention (e.g. `RelatedModelName_id`).

You could also replace the `slug_id` with the `Product` `id`

You can then use the resulting `$related` variable in your view, so assuming your using the above in a `Product` `show` controller method, you might do:

```
class ProductController
{
    public function show (Product $product)
    {
        $related = $product->relatedProducts(4, true)->with('categories')->get();

        return view('products.show', compact('product', 'related');
    }
}
```

```
@foreach ($related as $item)
    <h5>{{ $item->name }}</h5>
    <p>{{ $item->description }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can check with category id.**

```
$productsLike = Product::with('categories')
                 ->where('category_id_column', $category_id)
                 ->where('slug', '!=', $slug)
                 ->inRandomOrder()->take(4)->get();
```